# Can you fix my PHP If Statement, using a Href?

Tags: session, if-statement, cookies, echo, href

I am using an if statement and trying to get one of two statements to show, depending on the session running.
please help. thank you.

```
    if (session_name== "admin"){
    echo ("<a href="admin/logout.php">[Admin Logout]</a>");
    }else {
         echo "<a href="logout.php">[Member Logout]</a>";   
    }
    ?>
```

Also there is 2 syntax errors on the echo parts.

Comment: You never declared session_name as a variable.   $session_name=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You if you use double quotes around the argument to `echo`, you should use single quotes inside it for the HTML attribute, or vice versa (an alternative is to escape the inner quotes with backslash, but I never understand why people prefer this). And you need `$` before the variable name.

```
if ($session_name== "admin"){
    echo ("<a href='admin/logout.php'>[Admin Logout]</a>");
}else {
     echo "<a href='logout.php'>[Member Logout]</a>";   
}
```